# Control control local network interface (WiFi or Ethernet) to be connected when open boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket connection to remote server?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp

I want to control which local network interfaces (WiFi or Enternet or 4G LTE) is connected when I open boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket to connect to a remote server, is it possible? If so, appreciate an example.

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is usually done by explicitly binding the correct IP address to the socket before making a connection. With a native socket, this is the usual `bind()` system call. You need to check Boost's documentation to determine how to do it with Boost's wrapper for sockets.